# Powershell select combobox and execute a mstsc.exe

Tags: powershell

I need help and i sorry because i new in IT !

I want to make a combobox who when i select a server, have a button to open a mstsc.exe

I try fill this list in the combobox with a query like this:

```
$1= Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Servers, OU=Computer, DC=example, DC=com" | select name
```

I try make something modificate with this example but i cant :s

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null

function Button_OnClick() {

  "`$combo.SelectedItem = $($combo.SelectedItem)" | Out-GridView

  if ($combo.SelectedItem -eq 'Google') {
    Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe' -ArgumentList 'http://www.google.com'
  } elseif ($combo.SelectedItem -eq 'Microsoft') {
    $IE = New-Object -ComObject 'InternetExplorer.Application'
    $IE.Navigate2('http://www.microsoft.com')
    $IE.Visible = $true
  }

}

$combo = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$combo.Location = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList 5, 5
$combo.Size = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList 100, 25
$combo.Items.Add('Google') | Out-Null
$combo.Items.Add('Microsoft') | Out-Null
$combo.SelectedIndex = 0

$button = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button.Location = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList 5, 35
$button.Size = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList 100, 25
$button.Text = 'Launch in IE'
$button.Add_Click({ Button_OnClick })

$form = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Form

$form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedSingle
$form.MaximizeBox = $false
$form.MinimizeBox = $false
$form.Size = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList 60, 105
$form.StartPosition = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen

$form.Controls.Add($combo)
$form.Controls.Add($button)

$form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

Thanks and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to press a button and it will run a query and then dump the server names into the combo box. Simple.

You need to iterate through the names and add them to the combo box `Item` list, not the `SelectedItem` list.

```
$comboBox1.Items.Clear()
$1 = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Servers, OU=Computer, DC=example, DC=com" -Properties Name | select name
Foreach($name in $1) {
    $comboBox1.Items.Add($Name.name)
}
```

Don't forget to clear the `ComboBox` before running it otherwise you will end up with duplicate entries.

**EDIT:**

To To run the mstsc.exe with the selected code, put this in your button function.

```
mstsc.exe /v:$($comboBox1.SelectedItem)
```

Comment: I think he wants to fill the combobox with the AD users like your code does, but then to open a mstsc.exe for the selected user.

Comment: Yes, this i want. Fill the combobox with AD Computer and have a buttom to open a mstsc.exe from this list.                                                                                                    Sorry but i new with PS

Comment: All good, I just added the code that you need to throw into your button function.

Answer (score 0):

THanks Drew for help me!. I make the modification but now the powerbox just fill with one server. 
This query its ok because i do in a powershell console and get me the full list:

```
$1 = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Servers, OU=xx, DC=xxx, DC=xxx" -Properties Name | select name
```

I copy the code who i try to fill de combobox1. Thanks again for the help!

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
$comboBox1.Items.Clear()
$1 = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Servers, OU=xxx, DC=xxx, DC=xxx" -Properties Name | select name
Foreach($name in $1) {
    $comboBox1.Items.Add($Name.name)
}
$comboBox1 = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$comboBox1.Location = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList 5, 5
$comboBox1.Size = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList 100, 25
$comboBox1.Items.Add($name.name) | Out-Null
$form = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedSingle
$form.MaximizeBox = $false
$form.MinimizeBox = $false
$form.Size = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList 60, 105
$form.StartPosition = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen
$form.Controls.Add($combobox1)
$form.Controls.Add($button)
$form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```